# layout_weight TextViews between wrap_content TextViews not aligned

Tags: android, layout

I'm quiet new to android programming and stopped now on a problem which I am not able to solve.

I created follwing Layout:

[TextView wrap_content][TextView weight=5][TextView weight=5][TextView wrap_content]

It compiles as following Screenshot:

[image: a screen]

As you can see the second TextView gets Properly aligned.
Problem is the third and fourth TextView.
The third doesn't align to the second and won't align to the largest right TextView

Is this even possible?

Here's my Layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView

    android:id="@+id/SetCard_Item_txtCount"

    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"

    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:textSize="14dp" />

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/SetCard_Item_txtName"

android:layout_width="0dp"

android:layout_weight="5"

android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"

    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:textSize="14dp" />

    <TextView 

    android:id="@+id/SetCard_Item_txtType"

    android:layout_width="0dp"

android:layout_weight="5"

android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"

android:layout_marginRight="2dp"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:textSize="14dp" />

    <TextView

    android:id="@+id/SetCard_Item_txtCost"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"

    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:textSize="14dp" />

   </LinearLayout>
```

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

You have several `layout_width="wrap_content"` elements on each row that are of varying width. The layout weight mechanism only works on a second layout pass, distributing any *remaining* space in proportion to element weight. There's no guarantees of alignment.

You can make all the elements `0dp` wide with a non-zero width to make them align the way you want.

Comment: Which may result in a View were the first and fourth TextView will take more space than needed.

I want to have the two middle TextViews to have as much space as possible while showing the first and fourth TextView in a single Line

Comment: Here's a Screenshot of the way you suggested - still not what I want to achieve due to multiple Lines of the last Line and the huge space the first TextView takes: http://i.imgur.com/U9FyQPw.jpg 

On a Tablet, it will Result in an even more ridiculus View:

http://i.imgur.com/ZvUcUsN.jpg